# Docker compose Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am on Docker Version 20.07 and i am trying to Mount my config files.

My Docker compose looks like this -:

```
version: '2'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - './prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    container_name: grafana
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    volumes:
      - './grafana/config/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini'
```

And my Folder structure looks like this :-

```
Root
Monitoring_Stack
-- prometheus.yml
-- grafana.ini
-- docker-compose.yml
```

And when i do `docker-compose up -d`, I keep getting :-

```
ERROR: for prometheus  Cannot start service prometheus: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Docker/monitoring_stack/prometheus/prometheus.yml" to rootfs at "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type        
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Any help will be appreciated as to what i am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With host volumes, if the source doesn't exist, it will be created as an empty directory by docker (otherwise the bind mount would fail). This doesn't work if the destination inside the container is a file.

You do not have the file `./prometheus/prometheus.yml` in your directory structure. Instead, you have a `./prometheus.yml`. And similar for grafana. The path on the left is the path on your host, outside of the container. And after the colon, is the path inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

it is because you should mount folder and not the file to the container like this:

```js
 volumes:
      - './grafana/config/:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini'
```